# Sharing on Twitter with UIActivityViewController not working

Tags: ios, twitter, socialshare

Using Swift 3, building on my iPhone 6s (iOS 10.3.3), I'm trying to tweet via the `UIActivityViewController` and it silently fails. iOS tells me that the share completed succesfully (in `UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler`) but the tweet doesn't appear on my Twitter account (I'm both connected in the app and in the iOS settings). Also, the image preview doesn't show up in the share dialog, only the text. This is new, it was working fine a few day ago, I didn't release any version of my app since several months.

If I uninstall the Twitter app, everything works fine. I saw that Twitter released a new version a week ago (Sept. 12th), and I think it could be related. I read on a Twitter forum that they released a news share extension (https://twittercommunity.com/t/bug-in-ios-11/91490) to handle the news Social Sharing on iOS 11. Could it be related?

Is there any people facing this problem? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter released a new version of their application and it fixes the problem. It's now working on both iOS 10 and iOS 11.